# Is it possible that a directory copied and pasted to a particular directory using XHTML plugin in DITA OT 1.8.5

Tags: xslt, xhtml, dita, oxygenxml, dita-ot

Is it possible that a directory or a file copying from 'resource' folder in org.dita.xhtml to out put folder generated by the XHTML DITA OT transform.

If its possible using xsl changes in plugin its possible means provide me the code.

Any other way is there means please guide me the steps to do.

Please assist me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the [depend.preprocess.post](http://www.dita-ot.org/1.8/dev_ref/plugin-antpreprocess.html) extension point, or another one that fits your needs, to call [a new Ant target](http://www.dita-ot.org/1.8/dev_ref/plugin-anttarget.html).

**plugin.xml**

```
<plugin id="com.example.extendchunk">
  <feature extension="depend.preprocess.post" value="copyfiles"/>
  <feature extension="dita.conductor.target.relative" file="myAntStuffWrapper.xml"/>
</plugin>
```

**myAntStuffWrapper.xml**

```
<dummy>
  <import file="myAntStuff.xml"/>
</dummy>
```

**myAntStuff.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project basedir="." name="myAntStuff">
  <target name="copyfiles">
    <copy todir="foo">
      <fileset>
        <include name="**/*.bar"/>
      </fileset>
    </copy>
  </target>
</project>
```

Comment: @ Stefan Eike <copy todir="foo">, <include name="**/*.bar"/> please explain about those attributes specification inside the tags

Comment: "todir" is the target directory. "**/*.bar" means, all files with the file ending .bar from the current directory and all subdirectories. Google for "Ant fileset"

Comment: if i am want to copy files and folder from 'C:\DITA-OT\DITA-OT1.8.5-XHTML\plugins\org.dita.xhtml\resource' to output directory which is created by plugin like this (E:\out\xhtml) then how can i add attribures todir="foo" and name="**/*.bar" of tags <copy todir="foo"> and <include name="**/*.bar"/> please give me tags code. Thanks in advance